# VBA - Show entries in ListBox2 according to selected material in ListBox1

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I´m currently facing the problem, that my VBA program doesn´t work as I wish it would. I have between 2- x materials in 'List_Mat' (Material 100520, 100620, 100658, ...) (unlimited number of materials). These materials are the raw materials of products of which some information should be shown in the listbox 'List_Into'- one raw material can be used for multiple products and therefore with the selection of one raw material, multiple material should be listed in 'List_Into'. The material numbers are saved in the table "Stammdaten" in column K. Now I would like to click on one of the raw materials in listbox 'List_Mat' and than all products which are based on the selected raw material should be shown in listbox 'List_Mat'.

So far I have the following code:

```vb
Dim x As Variant
Dim List1Auswahl As String
Dim z As Variant
Dim y As Variant

List1Auswahl = UserForm1.List_Mat.List(List_Mat.ListIndex)
z = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stammdaten").Columns("K:K").Find(List1Auswahl, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

y = z
Do
y = y + 2
Loop While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stammdaten").Cells(y, 2) = "" And Not ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stammdaten").Cells(y, 5) = ""


For x = z To y
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stammdaten").Cells(x, 3) <> "" Then
With UserForm1.List_Into

.ColumnCount = 4
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100;100;100"
    .AddItem
        .List(List_Into.ListCount - 1, 0) = Sheets("Stammdaten").Cells(x, 1)
        .List(List_Into.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheets("Stammdaten").Cells(x, 2)
        .List(List_Into.ListCount - 1, 2) = Sheets("Stammdaten").Cells(x, 5)
        .List(List_Into.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sheets("Stammdaten").Cells(x, 4)
        
'.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stammdaten").Cells(x, 3).Value

End With
End If
Next x
```

I appreciate your help.

I´ve tried to use different codes but nothing worked so far.

[Material overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsdFn.png)
[VBA Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5te3Z.png)

Comment: If the materials are in K which column are the product in ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The product information are listed in different columns (A, B, D, E).

Comment: I´ve added two pictures to my description. The user can select one material in List_Box1 and than the code should check column K for the selected material and should show all relevant product information in List_Box2. In this case this would be the selected material 100580 which is the raw material of the products 200, 201 and 205, therefore the information of the products 200, 201 and 205 should be shown in the List_Box 2 = List_Into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler for UserForm1 like this ?

```
Sub updateItems4List_Into()

  Dim x As Variant
  Dim List1Auswahl As String
' Dim z As Variant
  Dim y As Variant

  Dim sht As Worksheet

  Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stammdaten")
  
  'List1Auswahl = UserForm1.List_Mat.List(UserForm1.List_Mat.ListIndex)
  'z = sht.Columns("K:K").Find(List1Auswahl, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

  '
  ' get material that is a 6-digit number:
  '
  List1Auswahl = UserForm1.List_Mat.Value

  'y = z
  'Do
  '  y = y + 2
  'Loop While sht.Cells(y, 2) = "" And Not sht.Cells(y, 5) = ""
  '

  '
  ' product info is saved in ABDE, E is material reference, E column index is 5:
  '
  '
  ' start searching from row 2:
  '
  x = 2

  With UserForm1.List_Into
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 4
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100;100;100"
    Do While (True)
      '
      ' check the material number, add it if required!
      '
      y = sht.Cells(x, 5)
      '
      If y = "" Then
        Exit Do
      ElseIf y = List1Auswahl Then
        .AddItem
          .List(UserForm1.List_Into.ListCount - 1, 0) = sht.Cells(x, 1)
          .List(UserForm1.List_Into.ListCount - 1, 1) = sht.Cells(x, 2)
          .List(UserForm1.List_Into.ListCount - 1, 2) = sht.Cells(x, 5)
          .List(UserForm1.List_Into.ListCount - 1, 3) = sht.Cells(x, 4)
        
        '.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stammdaten").Cells(x, 3).Value

      End If
      
      x = x + 1
    Loop
  End With
'
  Set sht = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  '
  Dim matListRange As Range
  '
  ' Column K is material number list, and Column L is their name:
  '
  Set matListRange = Sheets("Stammdaten").Range("K2").End(xlDown)
  Set matListRange = Sheets("Stammdaten").Range("K2:L" & matListRange.Row)
  '
  With List_Mat
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100"
    .List = matListRange.Value
  End With
  
  Set matListRange = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub List_Mat_AfterUpdate()
  updateItems4List_Into
End Sub
```

With a result like this:

[image]

[image]

I've assumed a data sheet like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello Jacouh, thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn´t work. After selecting one material, the List_Into shwos the following three products of the Excel file. For example - the selected material has its information in line 4, than List_Into shows the information from line 4, 5 ,6. 

Normaly the system should check column K for the selected material and than show the information of each product. For example - the selected material has its information in line 4, than List_Into should show the information from line 4, 8 and 11. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I´ve added two pictures to my description. The user can select one material in List_Box1 and than the code should check column K for the selected material and should show all relevant product information in List_Box2. In this case this would be the selected material 100580 which is the raw material of the products 200, 201 and 205, therefore the information of the products 200, 201 and 205 should be shown in the List_Box 2 = List_Into.

Thanks!

Comment: @Peet_Wackel, I've changed the code according to your description.